# Python PyQt5 Progress Bar is not progressing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

so basically i have programs that are meant to show the progress of reading an excel file line by line in the background. So far i have the following code:

excelresult.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QBasicTimer
import os, sys, xlrd, threading, time, pythoncom
import win32com.client
from time import sleep
from test import MyGlobals


class ExcelCheck(threading.Thread):
progPercent = 0

def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.event = threading.Event()

def run(self):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    try:
        while not self.event.is_set():
            excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
            wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook
            ws = wb.Worksheets("TC")
            va_title = ws.Range(ws.Range('I7'), ws.Range('I700'))
            i = 0
            for r in va_title.Cells:
                if r.Text != '':
                    i = i + 1
                    # print(r.Text)
            # print(i)
            # print(round(i / 178.0 * 100,0))
            # rounding off
            progPercent = round(i / 178.0 * 100.0)
            MyGlobals.x=progPercent

            print(progPercent)
        return progPercent
    except:
        print('Excel is not executed')



        # sleep(1)
        # self.event.wait()

def stop(self):
    self.event.set()
```

scm.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QBasicTimer
import os, sys, xlrd, win32com.client, xlwt, threading, time
from time import sleep
from ExcelResult import *
from test import MyGlobals
import threading

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.btn_active = False
    print('init_false')


def startBtnClicked(self):
    self.btnStart.setText('start!')
    self.btn_active = True

    print(self.btn_active)
    tmr = ExcelCheck()
    tmr.start()

    while(MyGlobals.x<=100):

        #print (MyGlobals.x)
        self.progressBar.setValue(MyGlobals.x)

    # self.progressBar.minimum = 1
    # self.progressBar.maximum = 100
    # for progPercent in range(1, 101):
    #     self.progressBar.setValue(progPercent)
    #     time.sleep(1)
def exitBtnClicked(self):
    # self.ExcelCheck()
    self.btn_active = False
    print(self.btn_active)
    # os.system("taskkill /f /im Scm21.Client.exe")
    # self.close()
    # Stop the progress of python
    self.sys.exit()
    tmr = ExcelCheck()
    tmr.stop()

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(446, 207)

    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

    self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
    self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 381, 23))
    self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
    self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")

    self.btnStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btnStart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 110, 75, 23))
    self.btnStart.setObjectName("btnStart")
    self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.startBtnClicked)

    self.btnExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.btnExit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 110, 75, 23))
    self.btnExit.setObjectName("btnExit")
    self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.exitBtnClicked)

    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 446, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "SCM21"))
    self.btnStart.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
    self.btnExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and, test.py

```
class MyGlobals(object):
    x = 0
```

So, i am able to get the value of the ProgPercent from the ExcelResult.py into the scm.py using the test.py but completely not aware how would i update the progressbar value.

I tried using a loop but it hangs the GUI.

Thanks.

Comment: change return progPercent to return self.progPercent

Comment: I would recommend that you use QThread instead of threading.Thread

Comment: @eyllanesc i am already getting the progress percentage value, how will it make a difference?

Comment: Also, I am completely unaware how to use the Qthread Methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Qthread:

```
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class ExcelCheck(QtCore.QThread):
    updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    running = False

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExcelCheck, self).__init__(parent)
        self.progPercent = 0
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.progPercent += 1
            self.progPercent %= 100
            self.updated.emit(int(self.progPercent))
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_active = False

    def startBtnClicked(self):
        self.btnStart.setText('start!')
        self.btn_active = True
        self.tmr = ExcelCheck(self)
        self.tmr.updated.connect(self.updateValue)
        self.tmr.start()

    def updateValue(self, data):
        self.progressBar.setValue(data)

    def exitBtnClicked(self):
        # self.ExcelCheck()
        self.btn_active = False
        self.tmr.stop()
        self.sys.exit()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(446, 207)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 381, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")

        self.btnStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnStart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 110, 75, 23))
        self.btnStart.setObjectName("btnStart")
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.startBtnClicked)

        self.btnExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnExit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 110, 75, 23))
        self.btnExit.setObjectName("btnExit")
        self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.exitBtnClicked)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 446, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "SCM21"))
        self.btnStart.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.btnExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. But, when i am replacing the Progress Update logic in this, the QT window closes immediately without showing any progress.

Comment: Hey, i got it working but the exit only works in the beginning for several seconds, after the progress, if we press the exit, the window as well as the exit becomes unresponsive and window hangs. Any suggestions?